# Other fragment for vertical an landscape picture

Tags: android, view, fragment, landscape-portrait

In app I have `ListView` when is clicked, new `fragment` will apear. In new fragment is picture. But some of them are portrait and some of theme are landscape. I want to create other fragment when picture is landscape. Where can I define which fragment I want to open? Any tutorials, examples?

OPEN NEW FRAGMENT:

```
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mCurrentPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(ARG_POSITION);
        }

        Resources res = this.getResources();
        location = res.getStringArray(R.array.streets);
        authorsNicks = res.getStringArray(R.array.authors_nicks);
        imageMain = res.getIntArray(R.array.images);

        if(??????????????)
           return inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_fragment, container, false);
        else
           return inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_fragment, container, false);
    }
```

In XML I have two files: one for PORTRAIT picture and one for LANDSCAPE.

Comment: Show what have you tried so far.

Comment: So far I have fragment with ListView and fragment with Portret view. I have no idea how can I check if picture is vertical or how set this information. One of way is to create list and notice when picture is landscape(array of boolean 1- vertical, 0-horizontal) but I belive there is better way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add your fragment to your activity programmatically, you can check to see if your picture is landscape or portrait, and then launch whichever fragment you'd like. See the documentation here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Adding

Your code will look something like this

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager()
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

if (landscapeImage) {
    LanscapeFragment fragment = new LandscapeFragment();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
} else {
    PortraitFragment fragment = new PortraitFragment();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
}
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

In order to determine whether your image is `landscape` or `portrait` - by which I assume you mean whether the image is wider than it is tall or not, you could load the image into a bitmap, and check its width vs its height.

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.my_image);
boolean landscape = bm.getWidth() > bm.getHeight();
```

Comment: it simple function. I don't know how to  send information when picture is lanscape. Should I create array and notice if picture is landscape? I belive there is better way

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. When you say landscape, do you mean that the device is rotated to the landscape orientation, or do you mean that the picture you want to display in your fragment is wider than it is tall? If you added some code, particularly where you are currently adding your fragment, it may help me to better understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: When I say landscape/portrait I mean picture. For Device I can use folder layout-land. I have fragment with ViewList and fragment with text and picture. When picture is in landscape position I would like to open it in other fragment.

Comment: ListView Yes, you are right. It's exactly what I want to do

Comment: Ah I see, you're also asking how you can determine whether an image is landscape or portrait? I've updated my answer.

Comment: That should be my question, because how to switch fragment is quite easy. I just don't know how to determine picture 'position'

Comment: I see. So, when you say `landscape` are you referring to an image being wider than it is tall? Or do you mean something else? If you load the image into a bitmap, you can compare the values returned by its width() and height() methods.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42539/discussion-between-serafins-and-groucho)